# Why can't I divide integers correctly within reduce in Swift?

Tags: swift, math, functional-programming, reduce

I'm trying to get the average of an array of Ints using the following code:

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
let avg = numbers.reduce(0) { return $0 + $1 / numbers.count }
print(avg) // 1
```

Which is obviously incorrect. However, if I remove the division to the outside of the closure:

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
let avg = numbers.reduce(0) { return $0 + $1 } / numbers.count
print(avg) // 3
```

Bingo! I think I remember reading somewhere (can't recall if it was in relation to Swift, JavaScript or programming math in general) that this has something to do with the fact that dividing the sum by the length yields a float / double e.g. `(1 + 2) / 5  = 0.6` which will be rounded down within the sum to `0`. However I would expect `((1 + 2) + 3) / 5 = 1.2` to return `1`, however it too seems to return `0`.

With doubles, the calculation works as expected whichever way it's calculated, as long as I box the count integer to a double:

```
let numbers = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]
let avg = numbers.reduce(0) { return $0 + $1 / Double(numbers.count) } 
print(avg) // 3
```

I think I understand the why (maybe not?). But I can't come up with a solid example to prove it.

Any help and / or explanation is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `int / int -> int`: the types must be promoted *first* to do floating-point division.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The division does not yield a double; you're doing integer division.

You're not getting `((1 + 2) + 3 etc.) / 5`.

In the first case, you're getting `(((((0 + (1/5 = 0)) + (2/5 = 0)) + (3/5 = 0)) + (4/5 = 0)) + (5/5 = 1)) = 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 = 1`.

In the second case, you're getting `((((((0 + 1) + 2) + 3) + 4) + 5) / 5) = 15 / 5 = 3`.

In the third case, double precision loss is much smaller than the integer, and you get something like `(((((0 + (1/5.0 = 0.2)) + (2/5.0 = 0.4)) + (3/5.0 = 0.6)) + (4/5.0 = 0.8)) + (5/5.0 = 1.0))`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. So why do the 2 reduce cases give different results when all inputs are Ints?

Comment: @KyleGillen Because `int / int -> int`. The precision loss occurs there at *each* reduction.

Comment: @KyleGillen because they're different operations.

Comment: Thanks. OK, I'm probably being slow now - but in the case of the reduce at some point the division is 15 / 5 which should = 3, no? Why would data loss occur in such an instance?

Comment: at no point you divide 15/5 in the first reduce. you divide each of 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 by 5 before adding them to your accumulator. for each of the first four, the result of division by 5 is zero.

Comment: Thank you very much @muhmuhten. That explanation is exactly what I was looking for. I really need to up my math skills ;)

Comment: well in this case it's less math so much as understanding how reduce works

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that what you are attempting with the first piece of code does not make sense mathematically.

The average of a sequence is the sum of the entire sequence divided by the number of elements.

`reduce` calls the lambda function for every member of the collection it is being called on. Thus you are summing and dividing all the way through.

Comment: the division is only being applied to $1 (note operator precedence), and the initial value of the accumulator is zero, the math is fine.

Comment: well, the math *would have been* fine if rational arithmetic were used. as we see, it is not.

Comment: Thanks @andre-artus. At some point that did come across my mind, so I assumed: (1+2) / 5 = 0.6 > (0.6 + 3) / 5 = 0.72 etc. which does indeed explain the top use-case ending with a result of 1. However, in the case where doubles are used instead - why does it work as expected?

Comment: @KyleGillen, muhmuhten is right, I read it as you are dividing the sum, when what you are doing is dividing each element by the count, then summing them (valid, but unnecessary).

Comment: @muhmuhten, you are right (more so the second time :)) . I had the element and the accumulator swapped (in my head).

Answer (score 0):

For people finding it hard to understand the original answer.

Consider.

```
let x = 4
let y = 3 

let answer = x/y
```

You expect the answer to be a Double, but no, it is an Int. For you to get an answer which is not a rounded down Int. You must explicitly state the values to be Double. See below

```
let doubleAnswer = Double(x)/Double(y)
```

Hope this helped.